# Emoji must be a string or Emoji/ReactionEmoji from getting a custom emote

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make my Bot react with a custom emote to every message a specific user sends.
My code currently is :

```
if (msg.content.startsWith("")) {
            msg.react(msg.guild.emojis.get("475766563719479296"))
        }
```

Even though I checked everything, I still get this error :

```
(node:13640) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Emoji must be a string or Emoji/ReactionEmoji
at Message.react (C:\Users\Lars\Documents\Bots\Support Bot [Resanance]\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Message.js:437:23)
at Client.client.on (C:\Users\Lars\Documents\Bots\Support Bot [Resanance]\index.js:40:17)
at Client.emit (events.js:182:13)
at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\Lars\Documents\Bots\Support Bot [Resanance]\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\Lars\Documents\Bots\Support Bot [Resanance]\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\Lars\Documents\Bots\Support Bot [Resanance]\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\Lars\Documents\Bots\Support Bot [Resanance]\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Lars\Documents\Bots\Support Bot [Resanance]\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
at Receiver._receiver.onmessage (C:\Users\Lars\Documents\Bots\Support Bot [Resanance]\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:137:47)
```

I don't know what could be wrong.
Could someone help me?

Edit:
I did try `msg.react("475766563719479296")` but it's just the Error unknown emoji.

Comment: can you post some more context code?

Comment: did you try using `msg.react("475766563719479296")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind turns out that i copied the wrong ID

Answer (score 3):

Try using this instead:

```
const like = client.emojis.find(emoji => emoji.name === "like");

const dislike = client.emojis.find(emoji => emoji.name === "dislike");

message.react(like);

message.react(dislike);
```