# Emoji must be a string or GuildEmoji/ReactionEmoji error while trying to make bot react with a custom emote

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

For the past few days I've been trying to make a command where it reacts to a message with a custom emote. It gives me an error in the console saying this:

```
TypeError [EMOJI_TYPE]: Emoji must be a string or GuildEmoji/ReactionEmoji
    at Message.react (E:\Projects\DiscordBots\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Message.js:546:23)
    at Client.<anonymous> (E:\Projects\DiscordBots\LordMoth\moth.js:98:17)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (E:\Projects\DiscordBots\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (E:\Projects\DiscordBots\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (E:\Projects\DiscordBots\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (E:\Projects\DiscordBots\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (E:\Projects\DiscordBots\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (E:\Projects\DiscordBots\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'EMOJI_TYPE'
}
```

I've tried the answers from [How Find Emojis By Name In Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52074768/how-find-emojis-by-name-in-discord-js) and [Emoji must be a string or Emoji/ReactionEmoji from getting a custom emote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51698217/emoji-must-be-a-string-or-emoji-reactionemoji-from-getting-a-custom-emote) but no luck. I'm also sending the message in a channel from the guild where the emote is from.

My current code:

```
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.content === "ok") {
        const mfi = message.guild.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === "MOTHIFEST");
        message.react(mfi);
    }
});
```

And another solution I've tried to do with the emote's ID that's actually in the discord.js documentation (https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=react):

```
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.content === "ok") {
        message.react(message.guild.emojis.cache.get("824436212034830356"));
          .then(console.log)
          .catch(console.error);
    }
});
```

I'm confused so much. Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried to log what the value of `mfi` is?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I've just tried that now, and it's still giving me the same exact error.

Comment: Well, yeah, you should comment out message.react(mfi) then :) You could also log a list of emoji names and ids using this: `message.guild.emojis.cache.each((e) => console.log(`${e.id}: ${e.name}`))` so you could see if the one you're looking for exists.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the emoji name is correct. Don't forget that it's case sensitive. Try to check the value of `mfi` and only react to the message if it's not `undefined`:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.content === 'ok') {
    const mfi = message.guild.emojis.cache.find((emoji) => emoji.name === 'MOTHIFEST');

    if (mfi) {
      message.react(mfi);
    }
  }
});
```

As `message.react` returns a promise you could also use `catch` to catch any errors:

```js
const mfi = message.guild.emojis.cache.find((emoji) => emoji.name === 'MOTHIFEST');

message
  .react(mfi)
  .then(() => console.log('Reaction sent'))
  .catch((err) => console.log(`Oops, there was an error ${err}`));
```

You could also log a list of emoji names and ids using the following example, so you could see if the one you're looking for exists:

```js
message.guild.emojis.cache.each((e) => console.log(${e.id}: ${e.name}))
```